# Why does my xfce4-panel keep crashing and immediately respawning itself many times a day?

Tags: linux, crash, xfce, xfce4, bug

A month ago, I installed Linux (Debian 12) on my PC. XFCE for the DE. Chicago95 theme.

Right from the start, and for this entire time, there has been a weird bug of some kind which makes the taskbar (xfce4-panel) visually "glitch out" visually, seemingly crashing, only to then immediately respawn itself again.

This happens many times a day, but I can never predict it by doing some action. It seems to happen entirely randomly.

When it happens, it annoys me for a couple of seconds and often causes major confusion by reordering the opened window groups in the taskbar slightly.

Initially, I kept running `sudo journalctl -n 100` right after it happened and scrolled down to the bottom to see if there was anything logged. There never was.

Then, the other day, somebody told me about the file `~/.xsession-errors`. This file *does* contain some potentially relevant stuff:

```
(xfce4-panel:1492): libtasklist-CRITICAL **: 00:23:19.508: tasklist-widget.c:3055 (xfce_tasklist_button_enter_notify_event): expression 'XFCE_IS_TASKLIST (child->tasklist)' failed.

(xfce4-panel:1492): libtasklist-CRITICAL **: 00:23:19.516: tasklist-widget.c:3055 (xfce_tasklist_button_enter_notify_event): expression 'XFCE_IS_TASKLIST (child->tasklist)' failed.

(xfce4-panel:1492): libtasklist-CRITICAL **: 00:23:19.524: tasklist-widget.c:3055 (xfce_tasklist_button_enter_notify_event): expression 'XFCE_IS_TASKLIST (child->tasklist)' failed.

(wrapper-2.0:1545): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 00:23:20.124: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

The "**CRITICAL**" parts make me think that this must be xfce4-panel crashing. But *why*?!

I don't use a bunch of weird plugins in the taskbar/panels. I don't do anything weird or exotic. All I want is to use my GUI without constantly waiting for that "crashing and respawning" process which is slowly driving me insane.

I have asked many times on IRC but nobody knows. I have also searched a lot online but find nothing relevant.

Some possibly useful information about my system:

```
libxfce4panel-2.0-4/stable,now 4.18.2-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xfce4-panel/stable,now 4.18.2-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xfce4/stable,now 4.18 all [installed,automatic]
```

There are no further updates. I am fully up to date.

Why does it keep doing this, and what can I do about it to make it stop?

PS: Please don't tell me to use a different DE since Gnome and KDE are both worse, and Chicago95 only works with Xfce. I have already invested so much in getting everything set up for Xfce. I just want it to stop doing this.